# If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ is convergent for $x=-3$, what can be said about convergence at $x=2$ and $x=3$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, solution-verification

**Problem**: Is the following True or False:

If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ is convergent for $x=-3 \implies:$

a) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n 2^n$ converges.

b) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n 3^n$ converges.

#### Progress

I found an extra set of notes that had the following theorem, which I could use to answer this question:

> If a power series $\sum c_nx^n$ converges for $x=b \neq0$, then it converges for $x$ with $|x|<|b|$.

From the above theorem, we can thus deduce:

a) Since $|2|=2<|-3|=3$, we know $\sum c_n 2^n$ converges. Thus TRUE.

b) Using the same theorem, we can also say that $\sum c_n (-3)^n$ converges $\nRightarrow \sum c_n3^n$ converges, since $|-3| \nless|3|$. Thus (b) is FALSE.
To determine whether or not $\sum c_n 3^n$ converges, a separate test must be performed.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: "I have absolutely no idea where to start" Please explain what leads you to want to solve this exercise while having "absolutely no idea where to start".

Comment: I am writing a test in next week, and found this question in a previous test paper. I was able to solve the rest of the paper quite easily, but for some reason this question has me stuck in the sense that I do not know where to start to show either true or false

Comment: This question HAS TO ring at least some bells, you studied power series, review the basic results in the field, what does the hypothesis gives you?

Comment: I think at least a more or less pretty easy counter example can be found for (b). Does conditional convergent series ring a bell?

Comment: @Did I came across another set of notes that had a theorem which could be used to answer the questions quite easily :). My set of notes did not include Power Series, since we had to make use of other materials for this section :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning for (a) is correct, but for (b) it is seriously flawed. "Using the same theorem, we can also say that" ... no, you cannot say *anything* since the condition of the theorem $|x|<|b|$ is not met. The theorem said "If condition C holds, then conclusion D is true". This does not mean that "if C fails, then D is false"; that would be another theorem to prove.

The correct way to handle question b) is by means of examples, such as 
$$
\sum \frac{x^n}{3^n n^2} \quad \text{ and } \sum \frac{x^n}{3^n n}
$$ 
in both cases, the series converges for $x=-3$. One of these converges at $3$, the other diverges.

Comment: Thank you! :). I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

b) is not true. For example, let $c_n=\frac{1}{3^nn}$.